# Why is my test case failing for the hailstones method?

Tags: java, unit-testing

Returns a string consisting of a Hailstone sequence beginning with the positive integer n and ending with 1. The
string should consist of a sequence of numerals, with each numeral followed by a single space. When a numeral m
(other than 1) appears in the sequence, it should be followed by nextHailstone(m).
Examples: nextHailstone(1) is "1 " and nextHailstone(5) is "5 16 8 4 2 1 ".

```
public static String hailstones (int n)
{

        int calculation = 1;
        System.out.print(n + " ");
        while (n > 1)
        {

          if (n % 2 == 0)
          {

             n /= 2;

           }
           else
           {

             n = (n*3) + 1;

           }
           calculation++;
    System.out.print(n + " ");



    }
        return " ";
}
```

The code works fine when I call the method in the main method but the test case for it is failing.

```
@Test
public void testHailstones ()
{
    assertEquals("1 ", hailstones(1));
    assertEquals("16 8 4 2 1 ", hailstones(16));
    assertEquals("7 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1 ", hailstones(7));
}
```

Those are the test cases. any insight into this would be great. thanks!

Comment: You may be correctly printing out the sequence, but you are not returning the string. You need a string to store the hailstones, so the unit test can pass.

Comment: You are returning `" "` that's why. Why don't you return your result?

Comment: @Ofisora:  That'd return `1` every time.

Comment: Edit your title to actually describe your Question, be *specific*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You return `" "` every time the function is called. You need to build up an internal string and return that as result.